# C++ bitshift wraps due to conversion?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, bit-shift, literals

Could someone explain this behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 32; i++){
        unsigned long test = 1u << i;
        cout << test << endl;
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
2147483648
1
```

Which makes sense until the end. Bit shift operators shouldn't wrap, but here it appears to be doing exactly that. I imagine it's because the literal '1u' is a smaller type than an unsigned long. Using '1ul' instead makes the behavior perfectly normal, so there must be something going on with the type conversion, but I'm curious to know exactly what and why!

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't wrap?

Comment: The behavior is undefined. The shift has to be less than the size of the shiftee. I’m sure this is a duplicate, but haven’t found it.

Comment: Shifting a 32-bit number more than 31 steps has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Warm welcome into the world of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @NeilButterworth, the link you marked as duplicate addresses signed integers. This post deals with unsigned integers.

Comment: @RSahu What? Where?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, from the post: `int a = 1;
    std::cout << (a << 32) << std::endl;`

Comment: @RSahu I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value of the right operand for bit-wise shift is negative or is greater or equal to the number of bits in the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.shift#1:

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

And there's no sense in explaining the behavior of undefined behavior, because it's undefined.

Comment: Not true. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.shift#2. The behavior is well defined for signed types.

Comment: @RSahu That paragraph is not an exception to the last sentence in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: @Rsahu My statement was only referring to the type used in the question (unsigned long), I don't know enough to speak for signed types.  Perhaps I should have been more clear.